# configuration Pycharm/odoo 12

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-12

i have a problem with the configuration of odoo 12 with pycharm on Windows 10 ( Python 3.6)

**This is the error** :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\python.exe" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Odoo 12.0/server/odoo-bin"
ERROR: couldn't create the logfile directory. Logging to the standard output.
2020-02-19 10:20:28,596 8216 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0-20200203 
2020-02-19 10:20:28,597 8216 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo.conf 
2020-02-19 10:20:28,597 8216 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['c:\\users\\asus\\appdata\\local\\openerp s.a\\odoo\\addons\\12.0', 'c:\\program files (x86)\\odoo 12.0\\server\\odoo\\addons', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Odoo 12.0\\server\\odoo\\addons'] 
2020-02-19 10:20:28,598 8216 INFO ? odoo: database: root@localhost:5432 
2020-02-19 10:20:30,813 8216 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\thirdparty\wkhtmltopdf.exe 
2020-02-19 10:20:32,873 8216 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on DESKTOP-GPEAI9D:8069
```

and thanks =)

Comment: Try to pass the full path of `odoo-bin`.

Comment: @Kenly i tried it and this is the error : python: can't open file '├ö├ç┬¼'C:/Program': [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: Please edit your question and add the changes.

Comment: I think it's just an control access problem, when you run the program without administration privilege he cannot create a file inside `programe files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **pycharm** then do setting like this.

[image]

- Script path: PathOf**odoo-bin**File
- Parameters: --config=pathTo**Conf**File

Comment: i tried it and this is the error :    **ERROR: couldn't create the logfile directory. Logging to the standard output.**